# IOS: Firebase Observer not removing Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove observer from firebase but its not working.
this is my code of adding observer

```
    self.ref = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Public/AuctionTypes/10/CurrentItem"];
    [self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists)
        {
            NSLog(@"Snapshot: %@", snapshot.value);

        }
    }];
```

removal code is:

```
    [[self.ref child:@"Public/AuctionTypes/10/CurrentItem"] removeAllObservers];

[self.ref removeAllObservers];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used FIRDatabaseHandle to remove firebase observer and now it works fine by using [ref removeObserverWithHandle:handler]